# Multiple checking at one time accesoryType

Tags: ios, xcode

So, there is a problem: when i checking a cell in table, another cell checked also, but i want only one checking at time. There is source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.symptoms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"name"];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSLog(indexPath);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: There's a typo: `tableView:di:` should read `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not reuse the cell.
Because when you reuse the cell you also reuse the checkmark-/accessory-state.
So why not removing the cell queuing.

You can try:

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictrionary *checkedState;
```

.m file:
(at top)

```
@synthesize checkedState = checkedState_;
```

(rest)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.symptoms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectForKey:@"name"];

    if(self.checkedState) {
      NSNumber *checkmarkStateNumber = [self.checkedState objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
      if(checkmarkStateNumber && [checkmarkStateNumber boolValue] == YES) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
      }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSLog(indexPath);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!checkedState) { self.checkedState = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; }


    BOOL checkmarkState = NO;
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        checkmarkState = YES;
    }

    [self.checkedState setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:checkmarkState] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**Update 1:**
Now it should also store the checkmark state!

Comment: it helped with multiply checking, but added new problem: now, when i check cell, scroll down and scroll up, cell became unchecked

Comment: Yes. You need to store the checked state in a Dataholder. You can use a NSMutableArray. Do you know how?

Comment: Do you have multiple sections?

Comment: It's okay, your code worked fine, problem was from my side. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to your table view controller:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath;
```

Synthesize the property in your table view controller's implementation:

```
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;
```

Add this line to `dealloc`:

```
self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
```

Add this to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
cell.accessoryType == (indexPath.section == self.selectedIndexPath.section && indexPath.row == self.selectedIndexPath.row) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Add this to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

The advantages are:

- you can still reuse cells;
- even if the view gets unloaded as a result of a low memory warning, it will restore the checkmark after the table view is reloaded.